# Cream of Tomato with garlic + cilantro stalks aroma

Tags: soup, tomatoes, garlic, vegetarian, restaurant-mimicry

I've been trying to crack this **Cream of Tomato** recipe for many decades now that is served in almost all Indian five star hotels and professionally managed kitchens.
At the end when it's served, it has a strong and the most fragrant aroma of garlic, cilantro stalks, nutmeg, etc but does not necessarily feel 'garlicky'.

Here's my recipe to start with:

1. Add oil+butter in a pan with black pepper corns. Add crushed tomatoes, garlic and cilantro stalks. Let cook for 15-20 minutes. Blend and then strain.
2. Start again with butter and nutmeg powder.
3. Add all purpose flour and then some milk and let cook for a couple minutes.
4. Pour the blended/ strained tomatoes. Let cook for 10 minutes. Test salt/ white pepper.
5. Serve.

***What can I do at the end to get the garlic aroma in soup?***
Thanks and best wishes.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Asking for recipes is off topic on this site, so this question will likely be closed. If you have a recipe that doesn't work for you feel free to edit your question and post the recipe, asking specific questions about how to get the result you want.

Comment: Done. I didn't realize that my question was tantamount to having asked for recipe and neither did I realize that asking for a recipe itself was off the table as well.

Comment: @OldSchool I don't see a recipe added to your question. Can you check it?

Comment: @OldSchool - you can find out what is acceptable in terms of questions (here)[https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help). As the question now stands I don't think it will be closed.

Comment: If it's served in almost all the 5-star hotels, someone probably has already leaked it, if not outright published it. If not, you could try getting a night job. ;)

Comment: I have checked the length and breadth of internet and I didn't see it.

Comment: I’ve never been to India so haven’t experienced the soup you describe. Looking at recipes online though, I see it is often served the with croutons. Is it possible that the croutons are fried in oil flavoured with garlic, coriander etc so that they act like a tempering, fragrancing the soup?

Comment: Thanks @Spagirl.. how to achieve oil flavored of garlic?

Comment: @OldSchool It isn’t something I’ve done, but I would try frying a crushed clove or two of garlic and some coriander stems etc in some oil, then scooping them out and using that oil to fry croutons.

Comment: @OldSchool : search for "garlic infused oil".  Typically you start with cold oil and sliced or crushed garlic, and then slowly heat it.

Answer (score 1):

This is mere theory/guesswork, but I wonder if they might do it like a tadka [tarka] you add to dall [lentil] recipes?

Fry garlic & other spices in oil, then pour over right at the end. Stirring in is optional, for presentation effect.

Here's a link to a rather elaborate tadka method, including smoking charcoal which sounds fabulous, though I've never tried it myself
https://www.cookwithmanali.com/dal-tadka/

Alternatively, my own 'cheat' to punch up the garlic in a dall recipe is to add powdered garlic right at the end. This punches up the fresh 'garlickiness' a lot, with very little effort. It has a tendency to go lumpy if you're not careful, so mixed in as a slurry is the easiest way to avoid that.

As to the coriander/cilantro, I can think of no method to get the bright, fresh smell & taste into a soup just before serving other than to make a quick purée & stir it in. I'm sure you would be able to spot the bits of bright green, though, done this way, but coriander really doesn't keep that bright flavour more than a few minutes once heated.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed view. Cilantro I can probably manage by using stock water that has excessive cilantro stalks. I am going to try the garlic powder suggestion sometime soon and write back here. Thanks again ..

Comment: They also might've used cilantro / coriander *root*.  It has a very strong flavor (without being overly soapy), but you have to go to an asian grocery store (or talk to a gardener) to find it.

Comment: @Joe - Yeah, supermarkets always chop the roots off. My local supplier doesn't. I have to say, though, that I've never understood this "soapy" thing people say when talking about coriander/cilantro. Maybe it's a regional issue. Where I live [UK] supermarkets sell stuff you've to crush before you can smell it [grown in UK]. My local Turkish store you have to keep it in a bag, it's so punchy and magnificent [grown in Turkey]. Neither would I quantify as 'soapy' in any respect.

Comment: @Tetsujin : it's believed to be a genetic thing (OR26A).  There are some chemical compounds in cilantro that not everyone can taste, and most people who can taste it find it to be really, really nasty.